# how to send database data to a MySQL server to update the server database

Tags: iphone, mysql, database, sqlite

I am developing Smoking counter and I need to send all the smoking record (about the time user smoking) to database on the server. The server database is MySQL database. I knew that I must have send data to PHP page/script, and this page/script will run on the data to insert record to database.

I would like to know: is there another way to update database, because I don't have knowledge about PHP. I used to work on java and c/c++/objective-c. If you know another way to do this task, please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know Java, C and C++, then you should be able to learn how to write your php script really quickly, just google a tutorial.

While could run a Java server using a servlet to insert the data, PHP is far easier to deploy, and you should only need to write a few lines of code.

I you do use PHP though one thing to remember when inserting to your database is to run all your parameters to add through mysql_real_escape_string

Edit:
To give an example, this script when configured would insert a name and location to a database:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
$person = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['person']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(location, person) VALUES('{$location}', '{$person}')");
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I can learn PHP to write some script. But I would like to ask, after I write the PHP page/script, where can I upload that page because the database is on server. Do I need to upload that page on the same server?

Sorry because this is maybe a stupid question.

Comment: Your PHP script would need to run on a server running PHP. If the DB is on a remote server then the DB server would need to allow remote connections, which is generally not a good idea unless you know what you're doing due to mysql injection attacks.

Comment: Your php has to be on a webserver that supports php. Your database can be in a different server(doesn't have to be on the same server that php is in). You just have to set up the php mysql_connect so that it points to the database server.

Web servers that support php - LAMP(Linux), WAMP(Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You may use any server side solution you like which has a MySQL interaction class library, e.g. Java servlet or C/C++ CGI application. You will also need a web server (e.g. Apache or Apache Tomcat) which will take care of HTTP requests.

PHP is not the only way to write programs which use MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can you this API hosted on github.com .

https://github.com/gwdp/Obj-c-MySql

It's free and very well documented .